# sand box redirection destroys sessions

Tags: asp.net, paypal, sandbox

why it happen when i redirect user to PAYPAL's sandbox (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com)  from my localhost then after returning to .aspx page (successful.aspx), it losses session,

e.g. SESSION["tempUser"], it works on everypage but not on Successful.aspx page, it returns null, i am working on this error for 2 weeks, but no progress, 
i tried different browsers, even different system, changed code a bit but nothing helped, its been 1month+ and after several posts on several forms , nothing helped even cookies have same problem, null upon return , my prior post.

Redirection page code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <h4> Congrats <b> <%# Session["tempSubAdminName"]%>  </b>, Your basic informaton has been submitted , For full activation you need to pay via paypal. Please click the PayPal icon given below. </h4>
</div>
<div>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="homeBtnImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/btnPayPal.gif"
      NavigateUrl= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=smile2_1355775057_biz@yahoo.com&item_name=MemberShip&amount=20&currency=USD&return=http://127.0.0.1:57135/Online%20Recruitment%20System-Final/paymentSuccessful.aspx?emailAdmin='1234' &cancel_return=https://www.google.com/" >PayPal</asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<h6>Or if you don't have paypal account, click <asp:HyperLink ID="paypalSite" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/" >here</asp:HyperLink> </h6>
</form>
```

Return to this age if successful

```
</head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
     <h5> Dear <%# Session["tempSubAdmin"] %>, You have successfully registered ,   Please wait for the approval by admin. </h5>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is Session["tempSubAdmin"] supposed to be the same as Session["tempSubAdminName"]?

Comment: the bottom line is that session got lost when i tried

Comment: can you share your codes?

Comment: How do you redirect and how do you come back?

Comment: using this lines i do redirect


 <asp:HyperLink ID="homeBtnImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/btnPayPal.gif"
      NavigateUrl= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=smile2_1355775057_biz@yahoo.com&item_name=MemberShip&amount=20&currency=USD&return=http://127.0.0.1:57135/Online%20Recruitment%20System-Final/paymentSuccessful.aspx?emailAdmin='1234' &cancel_return=https://www.google.com/" >PayPal</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: and when i complete transcation at sand box then i am supposed to return to success.aspx page, and it does but with session = null

Comment: check the code in my original post

the reason i want session is that i want to add '1' to data base which shows that user has paid adn now active , so for that reason i want to match session with user email in db and then inserting 1 for that user

Comment: wait for 2 min... i am preparing it for you

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining the way i have implemented. it may vary person to person.

1. First you have to create an account  on [developer paypal api](https://developer.paypal.com/). account.
2. Then create two test accounts, one for client and another for business(merchant).
3. Declare these values in the **web.config** file.

   ```
    <appSettings>    
       <!--these keys are for Paypal-->
       <add key="paypalURL" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com" />
       <add key="paypalAccount" value="arshad_Mer_biz@gmail.com" />
       <add key="websiteUrl" value="http://www.yourstie.com" />
     </appSettings>
   ```
4. Now you have to set paypal html varaible accordingly , for details [Paypal variables](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)
5. write following code in the **button_click** event

   ```
   string redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalURL"]+"/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick";
   string sellersEmail = "&business=";
   string buyersEmail = "&email=";
   string productName = "&item_name=";
   string amount = "&amount=";
   string shippingOption = "&no_shipping=";
   string noteOpton = "&no_note=";
   string returnUrl = "&return=";
   string cancelUrl = "&cancel_return=";
   string rmOption = "&rm=";
   string notifyUrl = "&notify_url=";
   string custom = "&custom=";

   // Merchant account
   sellersEmail += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalAccount"];

   //calling a method that will return current user email id.
   buyersEmail += GeneralClass.GetUserEmail();

   //optional value if you want to carry
   custom += GeneralClass.GetUseriD();

   productName += lblProdeutName.Text;
   amount +=lblAmount.Text ;

   shippingOption += "1";                      //1 means no shipping option;
   noteOpton += "1";                           //1 means no note option;
   rmOption += "1";                            

   returnUrl +=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websiteUrl"]+"/PaypalThankYou.aspx";
   cancelUrl +=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websiteUrl"] + "/PaypalCancel.aspx";
   notifyUrl += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websiteUrl"] + "/PaypalNotifyUrl.aspx";

   redirectUrl += sellersEmail + buyersEmail + productName + amount + shippingOption +    noteOpton + returnUrl + cancelUrl + notifyUrl + rmOption + custom;
   Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
   ```

Cancel page:- if user cancel the transaction from paypal.it works for localhost also.
Thank you page: after payment, paypal will redirect to the page.
Notify url: sometime its called IPN(Instant Payment notification). This is the place where you will get the value from paypal. it only works on hosted page. **it will not work on localhost**

Code for the **Notifyurl** page
add these `namespaces`:

```
 using System.Net;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

in the `page_load`:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         //Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strURL =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalURL"]+ "/cgi-bin/webscr";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest =Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        string strResponse_copy = strRequest;  //Save a copy of the initial info sent by PayPal
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //for proxy
        //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
        //req.Proxy = proxy;
        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response

        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            //check the payment_status is Completed
            //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            //process payment
            // pull the values passed on the initial message from PayPal

            NameValueCollection these_argies = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponse_copy);

            string pay_stat = these_argies["payment_status"];

            //.
            //.  more args as needed look at the list from paypal IPN doc
            //.


            if (pay_stat.Equals("Completed"))
            {
            //inserting the database
                int intUserID;
                int.TryParse(these_argies["custom"],out intUserID);
                objUserEntity.UserID=intUserID;
                objPapalPayment.strTransactionID = these_argies["txn_id"];
                objPapalPayment.dblPaymentAmount = Convert.ToDouble(these_argies["payment_gross"]);
                objPapalPayment.strBuyerMail = these_argies["payer_email"];
                objPapalPayment.dtmDateAppliedOn = DateTime.Now;
                objPapalPayment.blnIsGlobalAdvertisement = true;
                objSubscription.blnIsPaid = false;
                objSubscription.blnSubscriptionWithHeld = true;
                objUserFunction.AddPaypalPayment(objUserEntity, objPapalPayment, objSubscription, enmSubscriptionType.Global);                         
            }


            // more checks needed here specially your account number and related stuff
        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        }
        }
    }
```

**Then how will you debug on the localhost?** use `rm` value =2;  and paste the same code in the thankyou page's page_load event. it will work.

For further details :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers
[Paypal variables and its usage](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)
Hope , it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing this on your local machine.

Check what the value of the cookie ASP.NET_SessionId is before you redirect.

Then check the value after successful.aspx is called.

If the cookie is lost: Paypal is not able to do anything with your cookie. It can only be changed on the same domain (locahost).

I would test this without paypal: just have a simple page that redirects to your successful.aspx. If the cookie is lost, you might have a very short Session Timeout configured  or have some code running that deletes cookies (check in global.asax)